# How do I set Node path (Homebrew) for Sublime Text Prettier plugin configuration so it survives Node updates?

Tags: node.js, homebrew, sublime-text-plugin

I have Node installed via Homebrew. The path is /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/21.1.0.

I've installed the Prettier Sublime Text plugin (JSPrettier) which requires the Node path to be defined. Defining it as /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/21.1.0 gets it working.

However, whenever I update Node, the path changes.

How do I set this up so the Prettier Sublime Text plugin configuration and survive Node updates?

Manually updating the path works, but it's not very efficient.

Comment: What is the output of "which node?" Doesn't homebrew create a symlink to `/usr/local/bin/node`? If it does, you can just use this.

Answer (score 1):

When you install a package using **homebrew**, it puts a versioned copy in its *"Cellar"* and creates an unversioned link to it in its `bin` directory. That way, you just add the `bin` directory to your PATH and your shell can always find the latest versions of every package you have installed - so you should generally avoid using specifically versioned executables.

The locations of *"Cellar"* and `bin` directory differ according to the CPU architecture on a Mac:

- on Apple Silicon, **homebrew** uses `/opt/homebrew/Cellar` and `/opt/homebrew/bin`
- on Intel Macs, **homebrew** uses `/usr/local/Cellar` and `/usr/local/bin`

You can tell which one of the two locations it is using by running:

```
brew --prefix     # prints "/opt/homebrew" on Apple Silicon and "/usr/local" on Intel
```

So, if you get a long listing of `/opt/homebrew/bin` for the `htop` package on Apple Silicon, you can see:

```
ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin

lrwxr-xr-x  1 mark  admin    29 Jul  9 15:35 htop -> ../Cellar/htop/3.2.2/bin/htop
```

which means there is an unversioned, plain `htop` in `/opt/homebrew/bin/htop` which just points to the latest v3.2.2 `htop` in the *"Cellar"*.

**TL;DR**

Use the unversioned links in `/usr/local/bin` or `opt/homebrew/bin`  unless you really, really need a specific version of anything.

---

Note that if you are programmer/developer, the story is slightly more complicated. You will use *"include files"* (a.k.a. *"header files"*) and libraries (e.g. `libxyz.so`) and `pkgconfig` files (i.e. with `.pc` extension). These are linked in exactly the same way as executables, so you use:

```
gcc/clang -I /opt/homebrew/include -L /opt/homebrew/lib  # Apple Silicon
```

or

```
gcc/clang -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib        # Intel Macs
```

or, if you want your compilation/linking to work on either architecture:

```
gcc/clang -I "$(brew --prefix)/include" -L "$(brew --prefix)/lib" ...
```